# SharePoint List Filtering Stopped

Tags: sharepoint, list, filter, sharepoint-list

I have a user who can no longer filter any SharePoint list in IE. He gets the popup to display at the top of a column and A on Top, Z on Top, Clear filter... and the filter values appear. But when he select a filter value, nothing happens. Not any error or any indication that the browser is working. It just doesn't do anything.

I've checked his Internet Options > Trusted Sites Zone settings and his advanced settings, they all match my own. Filtering works correctly for him in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Joe

Answer (score 0):

If it used to work - have him clear the cache (Ctrl-F5 on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scripting problem. Has custom Javascript or Jquery been added to the site, page, or master page recently?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem began when a new DNS entry was made without a subsequent Alternate Access Mapping. Once I added the Mapping, the user could filter again.

Who would've put those 2 together :D